# Get count of available IP addresses on the subnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a question related to Azure virtual network.

I try to get count of available IP addresses on the subnet. 
For RDFE we have the following API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn592118.aspx

But for ARM I don’t find similar API. All that I found for ARM is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163583.aspx

Could you please help me? How can I get count of available IP addresses on the subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Powershell you can do something like this:

```
$network = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -name 'some-vnet' -ResourceGroupName 'some-network-resourcegroup'
($network.SubnetsText | ConvertFrom-Json).IpConfigurations.Count
```

This will give you the number of assigned ip adresses on the virtual network.

edit: 
if you are not using Powershell you can simply count the number of returned entries in the IpConfigurations section in the above linked RM api.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is correct. This is good way to get the number of assigned ip addresses on the virtual network. But for count of available ip we should use the following formula:

`code`
countOfAvailableIPs = Math.Pow(2, 32 - netmaskLength) - reservedIPs - targetSubnet.IpConfigurations.Count
`code`

where reservedIPs = 5 - it is reserved IPs for azure. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-faq/